# Xml generated with fields & attributes entered by webform

Tags: c#, xml

i have the following problem!
I need to generate an Xml Document in asp.net.  For this, i need to enter the following information:
- Number of tags.
- Name of each tags (example: , , , etc).
- Attributes of each tag (example: Alex... etc)..

I have already this function that received a List **(TAGLIST)** with the name of the xml tags.

```
public  void functionxml()
{
    string RutaSave             = string.Format(@"C:\xml.xml");
    var Serializer              = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
    TextWriter textWriter       = new StreamWriter(RutaSave);
    Serializer.Serialize(textWriter, TagsList);
}
```

But the xml generated by this function looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dictionary>
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>CAMPO1</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d4p1:type="q1:string" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">test</anyType>
    </value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>CAMPO2</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d4p1:type="q1:int" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2</anyType>
    </value>
  </item>
</dictionary>
```

Please, any help will be welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show an example of what your trying to produce, since it sounds like your having a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XMLWriter instead of XMLSerializer. XMLSerializer tries to produce a XML file for an object; some kind of serialization. It is more like a BinarySerializer but it produces XML format instead of byte arrays or streams. XMLWriter is a class which writes a hierarchy into a XML file.